# Which version of FCL is ROS Melodic MoveIt using?

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-melodic, fcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

On this [MoveIt link](https://moveit.ros.org/install/source/dependencies/) it says ROS Kinetic is using `fcl-0.5` and Melodic is using `master`.

After downloading MoveIt on a fresh install of Ubuntu 18, ROS Melodic, it seems the file structure for `fcl` still matches that of `fcl-0.5` and not of `master` on the [fcl link](https://github.com/flexible-collision-library/fcl).

Which is the correct version of FCL to use for ROS Melodic MoveIt ?

What progression does ROS MoveIt intend to use?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/337092/which-version-of-fcl-is-ros-melodic-moveit-using?/) by [ap](https://answers.ros.org/users/3948/ap/) on ROS Answers with karma: 42 on 2019-11-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to [ros/rosdistro/rosdep/base.yaml](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/8410f503ccb5769a46a1e4df609cfc9848fdcfe3/rosdep/base.yaml#L1811), the `libfcl-dev` key resolves to `libfcl-dev` for Ubuntu Bionic (which is what ROS Melodic is supported on).

Looking at [packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libfcl-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libfcl-dev) that gives us `0.5.0-5` as version on Ubuntu Bionic.

So it would seem to be `0.5.x` for both.

It's likely the page wasn't correctly updated since the initial instructions for Melodic were added (note the "TODO: test these instructions for Melodic and update this page." at the top of the page), and `master` was used at some point for Bionic/Melodic.

> What progression does ROS MoveIt intend to use?

I'm not sure I understand this.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1